# How can Batman fly with his suit, instead of skydiving?

Tags: dc, batman

Wingsuits are used for landing purposes. See this picture of Gary Connery;
he used this suit for a skydive.

[image: Gary skydiving in a wingsuit, all we can see is the sky in the background]

How can Batman fly with his suit, instead of just skydiving?

Comment: When does Batman fly with his suit?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite
Within the Arkham City/Origins continuity, he can gain height without thermals by diving and pulling up, so that's one case.

Comment: @SeanDuggan: yeah that’s true. Man that was fun in Arkham City.

Comment: OP should definitely mention the source (since there apparently is one) otherwise we will have to speculate what they're referring to.

Answer (score 7):

Batman doesn't fly, he glides.
Example instances:

- Dark Knight Trilogy
- Arkham Series (Video Games)
- Comics
- Animated TV Shows and DCAU Movies

Batman Beyond on the other hand does fly with the help of rocket boots.